# Dropdownlist binding in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dropdownbox

Let's say I have a dropdownlist with datasource in a page, I can create the dropdownlist and it is automatically fiiled with data in the datasrouce, I don't need to use .bind() method, but why I still see some programmers still use .bind() method in Page_Load? what's the purpose of doing it if ASP.NET automatically does the job for you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it because you have set it in `aspx` mark up. But if you specify datasource in code behind then you need to bind it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe works great in the simplest scenario.  However, what if you have to run through some business logic to determine what data to bind the drop down with?  What if you have other controls that determine what data is bound in the drop-down?  Furthermore, what if your database/data access setup is not compatible with a declarative data source?  All these are reasons to bind the drop down manually in code.

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdownlist is populated based upon a parameter in the query string, how would you do this?

You would do it like so right?

```
protected page_load {
      if(!IsPostBack) {
           ddl.DataSource = GetDDLItemsByQueryString(Request.QueryString["id"]);
           ddl.DataBind();
      }
}
```